# simple implemented method for human silhouette extraction (python,opencv)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

Is there any simple implemented method for human silhouette extraction in OpenCV? The method can be work only for video.

Here is a sample frame:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

For images like these, OpenCV's HOG (Histogram of Oriented Gradients) works very well. And example can be found [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/11/09/pedestrian-detection-opencv/). The example is in python, but it is not hard to create a C++ version if you want. The trained parameters are already there, so you can use it immediately.

If you are interested in deep learning based approaches, both SSD (Single Shot Multiple Box Detector) and YOLO (You Only Look Once) can detect persons.

All these methods can only exact a bounding box. For extracting the exact silhouette, you will need to combine the results with image differencing or background subtraction.